# Best Database Application for Larger Sites Handling users 20000-30000 a day

Tags: php, database

What is Best Database Application for Larger Sites Handling users = 5,000-30,000 a day.

Each user would probably make 60-130 query in total.

For Such website, What database application, should I prefer.

My Web Coding Language is `PHP`.

So, need something which will run with `PHP`.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of queries?

Comment: Database Queries to fetch post, article , user details..etc.,

Comment: To be honest, I think any mature database will do the job just fine.

Comment: @flup yup, just go with mysql and call it a day

Comment: I used to run "mybb" scripts but than when there was user more than 6000 a day, it started creating few problem, so i have to drop this plan, and now am moving for my own application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org/) is very good for this kind of application. It does not use a database instead it stores data in documents in a JSON format. It scales automatically and is very fast compared to mysql.

They have a PDO driver available for php and alot of other languages aswell.

Comment: Is it best among NoSQL database ?

Comment: I think it is mongodb or couchdb, they are quite similar. I prefer mongo due to the auto scaling and the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has no problem scaling to any size.

Depending on the amount of data and how the data is modeled, the free version of Oracle XE would be sufficient on a small single CPU database server.

Oracle is amazingly efficient and 100% rock solid.

In terms of scaling, the next step would be Oracle Standard Edition on a single CPU.  Then dual CPUs then Oracle Standard Edition and more CPUs and then Enterprise Edition even more CPUs and then onto clustered servers and hot fail-over servers....on and on.... and by that time you're your database needs are probably equal to Ebay's needs (and hopefully your income too).